# No Method Error while testing with Rspec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I get a No Method Error while Testing with Rspec. Here is my code for the Test:

```
scenario 'admin updates a commissionrate' do
  create(:assignment, user_id: @user.id, role_id: 1)
  sign_in(@user)
  commissionrate = create(:commissionrate, rate: 0.05)

  visit edit_commissionrate_path(commissionrate)

  fill_in 'rate', with: 0.05
  click_on 'Eingaben speichern'

  expect(page).to have_content('erfolgreich')
end
```

and this is the factory for the commissionrate:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :commissionrate do
    commissionrate     { Faker::Number.number(0.05)}
  end
end
```

I receive the error: `undefined method 'commissionrate=' for #<Commissionrate:0xbc5ac10>`

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel you are supposed to assign factory values to your fields/columns in your model. Is commissionrate a field or should you actually rename it as rate? Just check that and see. Also, it would be useful if you can give information such as the model name and the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to assign `commissionrate`, which is not a valid attribute of model `commissionrate`.

Try changing the line

```
commissionrate     { Faker::Number.number(0.05)}
```

to

```
rate     { Faker::Number.number(0.05)}
```

I can see that there is a column `rate` in `commissionrate` model in this line `commissionrate = create(:commissionrate, rate: 0.05)`.